# Dynamically generate meta tags and titles for a wordpress page

Tags: plugin-development

I have created a wordpress page that will output product details of a specific product from amazon: `wordpress/product?asin=123`

I'm just using the product page as a template and it really contains nothing. I'm just adding a filter to the content to put some contents into it.

I'm also using the wordpress seo plugin from yoast to take care of SEO stuff but it seems to be getting in the way. I currently have this code:

```
function ecom_title_filter($title){

    if(is_singular()){
        if(!empty($_GET['asin'])){
            if($title == 'Product Details Page'){
                $asin = $_GET['asin'];
                $titles = get_titles($asin);
                if(count($titles) == 1){
                    $title = $titles[0];
                }else{
                    $index = 1;
                    $title = '';
                    $title_count = count($titles);
                    foreach($titles as $item_title){

                        if($title_count > $index){
                            $title .= $item_title . ', ';
                        }else{
                            $title .= $item_title;
                        }

                        $index++;
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

    return $title;
}
```

Then I'm adding it into the `the_title` and `wp_title`:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'ecom_title_filter');
add_filter('wp_title', 'ecom_title_filter');
```

The problem is that the page still retains the old page title which is `Product Details Page` and not the title that I'm returning from the method above. The method returns what I expect it to return so the problem is not the method. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either deactivate the filter from the SEO plugin for that page with `remove_filter()` or use a later priority argument like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'ecom_title_filter', PHP_INT_MAX );
add_filter( 'wp_title',  'ecom_title_filter', PHP_INT_MAX );
```